# Dart tryParse double vs string of double

Tags: string, parsing, dart, double

There seems to be some inconsistency with the way tryParse is used in Dart or I'm going about it a silly way, likely the latter.

When we use the int.tryParse statement, if we pass it 10.0 as a double, we would expect to get 10 which we do.

```
print(int.tryParse(10.0.toString())); ==> 10
```

If we pass it 10.0 as a string, it will return null.

```
print(int.tryParse('10.0')); ==> null
```

I find this a bit strange as I would have thought 10.0.toString() is equivalent to '10.0'.
Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Are you testing this in dartpad or a Flutter / Dart app.

Comment: I've tested it in both flutter and Dartpad. I originally had the problem in Flutter then tested it in Dartpad.

Comment: You could have easily tested and found that `10.0.toString()` is **not** equivalent to `10.0` as an answer suggests. Additionally, do not add the flutter tag for questions that are not directly related to flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between web compiler and native code.

When Dart is compiled to the web (to JavaScript), all numbers are JavaScript numbers, which effectively means doubles.
That means that the integer 10 and the double 10.0 is *the same object*. There is only on "10" value in JavaScript.
So, when you do `toString` on that value, it has to choose, and it chooses `"10"` over `"10.0"`.

When run natively, the double 10.0 and the integer 10 are two different objects, and their `toString`s are `"10.0"` and `"10"` respectively.

The `int.tryParse` function does not accept `"10.0"` as input, which is why it returns `null`.
So, when testing on the web (including dartpad.dev), `int.tryParse(10.0.toString())` succeeds because the `toString` is `"10"`, and when testing natively the same code gives `null` because the `toString` is `"10.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

`10.0.toString()` returns '10', not '10.0'. That's why you have different results.  [Here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39800) is just the same question. So, as I understand it, we have:

- dart `10.0` parses as `int` on js target (and there is not such a big difference between `int` and `double` on js target, as said on the link);
- dart `10.0` parses as `double` on dart VM, but `toString` returns the shortest possible text representation of that number, that is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compiler behaviour. I can't find someone reporting this issue. Maybe when you have zeroes after the comma, the toString method will round it. If all zeroes after comma, then it will convert to int.